# How to remove commas between double quotes in PHP

Tags: php, regex, quotes, double-quotes

Hopefully, this is an easy one.  I have an array with lines that contain output from a CSV file.  What I need to do is simply remove any commas that appear between double-quotes.

I'm stumbling through regular expressions and having trouble.  Here's my sad-looking code:

```
<?php    

$csv_input = '"herp","derp","hey, get rid of these commas, man",1234';

$pattern = '(?<=\")/\,/(?=\")'; //this doesn't work

$revised_input = preg_replace ( $pattern , '' , $csv_input);

echo $revised_input;

//would like revised input to echo: "herp","derp,"hey get rid of these commas man",1234

?>
```

Thanks VERY much, everyone.

Comment: Is that the actual code? You don't appear to be delimiting your expression.

Comment: Regex cannot do this. You'll have to write a parser. Also account for escaped quotation marks.

Comment: It's just sample code that contains a string (that I'm calling csv_input) that my real script would be dealing with.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Original Answer

You can use [`str_getcsv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) for this as it is purposely designed for process CSV strings:

```
$out = array();
$array = str_getcsv($csv_input);
foreach($array as $item) {
    $out[] = str_replace(',', '', $item);
}
```

`$out` is now an array of elements without any commas in them, which you can then just implode as the quotes will no longer be required once the commas are removed:

```
$revised_input = implode(',', $out);
```

### Update for comments

If the quotes are important to you then you can just add them back in like so:

```
$revised_input = '"' . implode('","', $out) . '"';
```

Another option is to use one of the `str_putcsv()` (not a standard PHP function) implementations floating about out there on the web such as [this one](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php#91170).

Comment: This is very close!  I need the quotes to remain in the output string, however.  With your code, $revised_input echoes: herp,derp,hey get rid of these commas man,1234

Comment: @SfahBbbzfhiuj I have updated my answer with a solution for that for you.

Comment: It places double-quotes around everything, but I think that would still work fine!  Thank you!

Comment: If you don't want the numbers quoted then you could use one of the `str_putcsv()` I linked to so you can make use of the escaping etc provided by PHPs CSV functions.

Answer (score 2):

This is a very naive approach that will work only if 'valid' commas are those that are between quotes with nothing else but maybe whitespace between.

```
<?php    

$csv_input = '"herp","derp","hey, get rid of these commas, man",1234';

$pattern = '/([^"])\,([^"])/'; //this doesn't work

$revised_input = preg_replace ( $pattern , "$1$2" , $csv_input);

echo $revised_input;

//ouput for this is: "herp","derp","hey get rid of these commas man",1234
```

It should def be tested more but it works in this case.

Cases where it might not work is where you don't have quotes in the string.

one,two,three,four -> onetwothreefour

EDIT : Corrected the issues with deleting spaces and neighboring letters.

Comment: Hey, that's even closer!  But, of course, the output says 'heet rid of these commaan' instead of 'hey get rid of these commas man'

Comment: Honestly, I think your solution was the closest to what I was originally looking for.  Thanks for the help, Jerry!

Comment: Hey @SfahBbbzfhiuj, hahaha. If only I had tested some more and looked at the output more closely. Alas! Anyway, I edited it and now, at least for the case you posted it works. Still, Treffynnon's answer is way better since you won't have to work around the quotes between the strings.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I haven't been lazy and written a small function to do exactly what you need:

```
function clean_csv_commas($csv){
    $len = strlen($csv);
    $inside_block = FALSE;
    $out='';
    for($i=0;$i<$len;$i++){
        if($csv[$i]=='"'){
            if($inside_block){
                $inside_block=FALSE;
            }else{
                $inside_block=TRUE;
            }
        }

        if($csv[$i]==',' && $inside_block){
            // do nothing
        }else{
            $out.=$csv[$i];
        }

    }
    return $out;
}
```

Comment: This was the only thing that solved my problem with str_getcsv. I have a file with millions of lines, and some lines were erring out due to commas in the field even though I was specifying the encapsulation.

Answer (score 0):

You might be coming at this from the wrong angle.

Instead of removing the commas from the text (presumably so you can then split the string on the commas to get the separate elements), how about writing something that works on the quotes?

Once you've found an opening quote, you can check the rest of the string; anything before the next quote is part of this element. You can add some checking here to look for escaped quotes, too, so things like:

```
"this is a \"quote\""
```

will still be read properly.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly an answer you've been looking for - But I've used it for cleaning commas in numbers in CSV.

`$csv = preg_replace('%\"([^\"]*)(,)([^\"]*)\"%i','$1$3',$csv);`

"3,120", 123, 345, 567  ==> 3120, 123, 345, 567